# knockout.js mouseover flicker with bound inline elements

Tags: events, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Using knockout.js, I have `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on a containing `<div>`. The handlers toggle boolean observables. Within the `<div>` is a `<p>` whose visibility is bound to those booleans. i.e. rolling over the `<div>` reveals the `<p>`. The contents of the `<p>` are bound to observables in the model.

What I've found is that if the bound contents of `<p>` contains an inline element - e.g. `<em>` - rolling over the text within the `<em>` causes the `<p>` to flicker. The same seems to happen for any inline element. If the contents of the `<p>` are not bound, the issue does not occur.

I have found a workaround for my application by using JQuery's `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

All 3 cases are demonstrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zimady/EyEzx/).

Is this expected behaviour, a bug or an oversight on my part? Is there a workaround that doesn't depend on the JQuery events?

(issue verified in Chrome 21.0, Safari 6.0, and FF 10.0.2 in OS X 10.7.4 and Chrome and IE in Windows 7)

Comment: [Ben Nadel states](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm) that the mouseover/mouseout events have issues with nested elements. That compounded by the fact that your element's visibility is affected by this causes the flickering. Just don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the article @Jeff: very informative. I'm convinced of the shaky ground I stand on using mouseover and mouseout!

That said, I do still think there is potentially an issue with ko that could do with attention. Note that the issue does not surface if the content of `<p>` is not bound: i.e. there is definitely something iffy with binding child elements in this case and part of my question is about trying to get to the bottom of that (I appreciate there are several questions rolled into one here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the difference between `mouseleave` and `mouseout`, and is expected behaviour. This is outlined in this article here: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/

If I were to do this, I would do it with css. Unless you need to really know something or perform advanced actions/operations based on mouse hover, you can control basic visibility very easily (knockout not necessary in demo):

http://jsfiddle.net/WLShQ/

HTML:

```
<div class="hoverbox">
    <p>Mouse over here...</p>
    <p class="extra">Then roll over <em>this red text</em></p>
    <p class="extra">It doesn't flicker!</p>
</div>
```

And the css

```
div.hoverbox p.extra {
    display: none;
}

div.hoverbox:hover p.extra {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for jolting me out of ko headspace and reminding me that CSS might be more elegant.

I'm going with this suggestion as it also had the advantage that there are no repeated binding declerations in other places this interaction is used.